# Why differences in output using SUPERGLOBAL in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, echo, server, superglobals

I am getting error by running following code:

```
<?php
    //superglobal.php

    foreach($_SERVER as $var=>$value)
    {
        echo $var=>$value.'<br />';     //this will result in to following error: 
                                                    //Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ';' in 
                                                    //C:\xampp\htdocs\w_j_gilmore\CH_03_PHP_BASICS\superglobal.php on line 6
    }
?>
```

And following code runs successfully

```
<?php
    //superglobal.php

    foreach($_SERVER as $var=>$value)
    {
        echo "$var=>$value<br />";  
    }
?>
```

Printing in single quotation and double quotation is difference.
**WHY?**

Comment: yes. thats the correct behavior `$var=>$value` should return a parse error since `=>` is used for key pair used in arrays. well this `'=>'` is just treated as literal strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the 2 is that in the first you are trying to use the `=>` operator (which is not valid in that place, so will result in a syntax error), while in the second you print a string which happens to have the characters `=` and `>` in it.

The second effectively could be rewritten as:

```
<?php
    //superglobal.php

    foreach($_SERVER as $var=>$value)
    {
        echo $var . "=>" . $value . "<br />";  
    }
?>
```

If you are just trying to output `$_SERVER` for debug reasons, I suggest using [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) or [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

```
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not quoted the string:

```
echo $var=>$value.'<br />';
```

quoted would look like this:

```
echo '$var => $value <br />';
```

if single quoted, variables are not interpreted.